# Localhost running Bitnami even after uninstalling Bitnami

Tags: php, xampp, localhost, bitnami

I was using Bitnami to setup and run wordpress. When I ran into a few problems, I decided to change the software to XAMPP. **Here** is where the **problem arises**. When I type localhost on my web browser it shows the Bitnami welcome page. Shouldn't the localhost of XAMPP come ? How can I fix this issue. Below is a screen shot of my browser when I type localhost.

[image]

Comment: Did you install bitnami? If not, then that webserver is going to be hogging port 80 and won't the apache in wamp bind to it. You can't have two different webservers serving up data on the same port.

Comment: I forgot to mention in my question Marc. I have uninstalled Bitnami and even removed the Bitnami folder (restarted too :) ) yet I am facing the issue

Answer (score 5):

This was not a problem with Bitnami. Cleared my browser cache and history and XAMPP homepage showed up. False alarm!

Answer (score 0):

Just clear the cache..
 open the localhost and press Ctrl+F5